# What does under armor actually do?

Tags: exercise, clothing

I have wondered this for so long. Because I live in Florida, and I've been told that I need under armor for working out outside because it supposedly works like magic to take moisture away from your body so you don't sweat at all. I'm considering using it for when I go on nature trails. But I don't exactly know what under armor even does.

My goal is to find some clothing that will help me in Florida because it is so hot outside and I sweat ridiculously if I wear anything cotton. For example I have this Calvin Klein black cotton shirt… I wore it yesterday to walk around for 20 minutes at 7 o'clock when the sun had already gone down… So the black texture wasn't really a problem because the sun wasn't beating down on me but it was soaking wet afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Much of Under Armour's product-line is intended as a 'wicking-layer' - made of fabrics that are really good at drawing sweat away from your body and letting it evaporate on the surface. Cotton tends to not be very good at this in comparison.

They allow you to remain cool, dry, protected from wind, warm, and comfortable through a wide range of temperatures and activity-levels.

Comment: They use different fabrics though in all of their clothing. Some are 100% polyester, while others are this different material that is much more stretchy